# Regex for required field?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i need a regular expression that checks if the multiline textbox has been left emtpy. It should match on anything except whitespace. Im using ASP.NET.

I know i could use a Required Field Validator, but this will not allow me to run a custom javascript script on failed validation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\S` predefined set. it will match anything that is not whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = textBox.value;
text = text.replace(/^\s*/,'').replace(/\s*$/,''); // trimming
if(text){
  // run your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `CustomValidator`, as `RegularExpressionValidator` doesn't support empty strings. But you must define `ValidateEmptyText=true`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^[\s\t\r\n]*\S+
```

test => http://jsfiddle.net/KFCHM/

Comment: Can't you just check whether any non-space character is apperant? http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/KFCHM/1/

Comment: +1 -> i really did not know that \S could be used for tabs and lines :)